# How to update multiple columns for user account information in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have been trying to let my users update their information, so the first problem is, I keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: new_user_address in D:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce1\resetinfo.php on line 27

But I made sure that it was defined in my code. The next error is this:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in D:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce1\resetinfo.php on line 70

I am not sure where this error is coming from but I assume it's from the first error. Now I will show you the code.

There was a time when I made my update statements - instead of:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET 
user_address = '$new_user_address',
user_city = '$new_user_city', 
user_country = '$new_user_country', 
postal_code = '$new_postal_code' 
WHERE id = ?";
```

I used:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET 
user_address = ?,
user_city = ?, 
user_country = ?, 
postal_code = ?' 
WHERE id = ?";
```

and it properly redirects me to my profile page but there are not updates to the data.

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();// Initialize the session

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "dbconfig.php";
 $query = "SELECT user_address, user_country, user_city, postal_code FROM users WHERE id ='".$_SESSION['id']."';";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $new_user_address = $row['user_address'];
    $new_user_country = $row['user_country'];
    $new_user_city = $row['user_city'];
    $new_postal_code = $row['postal_code'];
}
$new_user_address_err = $new_user_city_err = $new_user_country_err = $new_postal_code_err = "";


// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate new password
        if(empty(trim($_POST["new_user_address"]))){
   $new_user_address_err = "City is empty.";
    } else{
        $new_user_address = trim($_POST["new_user_address"]);
    }

     if(empty(trim($_POST["new_user_city"]))){
   $new_user_city_err = "City is empty.";
    } else{
        $new_user_city = trim($_POST["new_user_city"]);
    }


    if(empty(trim($_POST["new_user_country"]))){
   $new_user_country_err = "Country is empty.";
    } else{
        $new_user_country = trim($_POST["new_user_country"]);
    }   

    if(empty(trim($_POST["new_postal_code"]))){
   $new_posta_code_err = "Postal Code is empty.";
    }elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["new_postal_code"])) < 6){
        $new_postal_code_err =  "Postal Code must have 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $new_postal_code = trim($_POST["new_postal_code"]);
    }  






    // Check input errors before updating the database
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET 
        user_address = '$new_user_address',
        user_city = '$new_user_city', 
        user_country = '$new_user_country', 
        postal_code = '$new_postal_code' 
        WHERE id = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $param_user_address, $param_user_city, $param_user_country, $param_postal_code, $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_user_address = $new_user_address;
            $param_user_city = $new_user_city;
            $param_user_country = $new_user_country;
            $param_postal_code = $param_postal_code;
            $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // After udpating everythin.
                header("location: profile.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        // Close statement



    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}

?>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="container text-white">
<div class="container px-5"> 
      <h1 class="display-2 black-neon text-center" style="font-family: 'Bungee';">Rest your password!
</h1><br><br>



        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
           <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($new_user_address_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Address</label>
                <div class="bg-white d-flex">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="new_user_city" value="<?php echo $new_user_address; ?>">
                   <div class="align-items-end"><a class="btn btn-lg disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
                       <span class="oi oi-person" ></span></a></div></div>
                    <span class="form-text"><?php echo $new_user_address_err; ?></span>
              </div>

            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($new_user_city_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>City</label>
                <div class="bg-white d-flex">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="new_user_city" value="<?php echo $new_user_city; ?>">
                   <div class="align-items-end"><a class="btn btn-lg disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
                       <span class="oi oi-person" ></span></a></div></div>
                    <span class="form-text"><?php echo $new_user_city_err; ?></span>
              </div>

            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($new_user_country_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Country</label>
                <div class="bg-white d-flex">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="new_user_country" value="<?php echo $new_user_country; ?>">
                   <div class="align-items-end"><a class="btn btn-lg disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
                       <span class="oi oi-person" ></span></a></div></div>
                    <span class="form-text"><?php echo $new_user_country_err; ?></span>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($new_postal_code_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Postal Code</label>
                <div class="bg-white d-flex">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="new_postal_code" value="<?php echo $new_postal_code; ?>">
                   <div class="align-items-end"><a class="btn btn-lg disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
                       <span class="oi oi-person" ></span></a></div></div>
                    <span class="form-text"><?php echo $new_postal_code_err; ?></span>
              </div>

  <input class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" type="submit" value="reset">

</form>
    </div>
      </div>
<br><br><br>
<?php 
    include_once ("footer.php");
?>
```

This code is actually an edit of this code -

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
require_once ("header.php");

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "dbconfig.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$new_password = $confirm_password = "";
$new_password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate new password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["new_password"]))){
        $new_password_err = "Please enter the new password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["new_password"])) < 6){
        $new_password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $new_password = trim($_POST["new_password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm the password.";
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($new_password_err) && ($new_password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before updating the database
    if(empty($new_password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $param_password, $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_password = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Password updated successfully. Destroy the session, and redirect to login page
                session_destroy();
                header("location: login.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="container text-white">
<div class="container px-5"> 
      <h1 class="display-2 black-neon text-center" style="font-family: 'Bungee';">Rest your password!
</h1><br><br>



        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($new_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">

                <label>New Password</label>
                <div class="bg-white d-flex">
                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="new_password" value="<?php echo $new_password; ?>">
                   <div class="align-items-end"><a class="btn btn-lg disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
                       <span class="oi oi-person" ></span></a></div></div>
                    <span class="form-text"><?php echo $new_password_err; ?></span>
              </div>


            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <label>Confirm Password</label>
       <div class="bg-white d-flex">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="password" name="confirm_password">
          <div class="align-items-end"><a class="btn btn-lg disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
           <span class="oi oi-person" ></span></a></div></div>
      <span class="form-text"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
    </div>
  <input class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" type="submit" value="Login">

</form>
    </div>
      </div>
<br><br><br>
<?php 
    include_once ("footer.php");
?>
```

I expect to get redirected to the profile page while having the data on my sql update. Please help me!

Comment: It turns out when I use:
$sql = "UPDATE users SET 
user_address = ?,
user_city = ?, 
user_country = ?, 
postal_code = ?' 
WHERE id = ?";

the city and country gets updated while the address and postal_code doesnt,

Comment: Regarding the "undefined index" error: I believe you get this error because you're attempting to `trim()` values before checking whether they're `empty()`.

Comment: the order when you assign values and set it to bind the sql matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET 
user_address = ?,
user_city = ?, 
user_country = ?, 
postal_code = ?' 
WHERE id = ?";
```

Change the order of operation to this:

```
// Set parameters
$param_user_address = $new_user_address;
$param_user_city = $new_user_city;
$param_user_country = $new_user_country;
$param_postal_code = $param_postal_code;
$param_id = $_SESSION["id"];
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $param_user_address, $param_user_city, $param_user_country, $param_postal_code, $param_id);
```

Comment: It's working alright, my new_postal_code keeps updating to - Empty field (for example, I set in myphpadmin: postal_code - 3322SS, but when I use resetinfo.php, it gives an empty field), can you help me locate where the error might be? Other fields are upading just fine. It's just the postal_code.

EDIT: I found the error, it's the $param for postal code, 

THANKS FOR THE HELP SIR!!!